# Running Script in Emulator for Seetest

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt

I am new to seetest.I recorded the script using seetest and converted  the code in Eclipse(Testng). But everytime running the code I need to start the emulator manually. IS there any way so that I can open using the code itself. If so ,Please help me with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Place all the seetest jars in your library
create an instance of your SeeTest client(say my insatnce name is client)
and call the client as follows

client.open()

if you have connected more than one device then pass your device name as the paramenter

client.open("myios")

Comment: As much i have seen , Seetest only works with real devices but not with emulator. Please  have one more for check for this.

Answer (score 0):

By emulator, I hope you implied device reflection in the SeeTest.

For SeeTest scripts to run on the device, you have to connect the device to computer. Add the device to SeeTest, then double click on the device to see the actions being performed as part of script.

To open the device in SeeTest, just use client.open("***DeviceName***").
For Android app: add "adb:" as prefix for device name
For iOS app: add "ios_app:" as perfix for device name